# Type ŭ (u with breve) on Canadian Multilingual Standard

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

I am using the Canadian Multilingual Standard keyboard layout to type the letters with hats of Esperanto (`ĉ`, `ĵ`, etc.), but I can't type `ŭ` (a `u` with a breve, not caron.)

How can this be typed with the Canadian Multilingual Standard? I am fairly sure it can be done, but there are close to no sources of info on this keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, I have found a solution.

You can type a `ŭ` by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+\`, releasing, and then pressing `u`.

Answer (score 1):

IBPXs answer is correct, but just need to add that the ctrl+shift have to be the right-side keys, not the left.

Multaj dankoj!

Answer (score 0):

ŭ The Ctrl has to be the one on the right side; the shift can be the left one.  If your printed characters on the keys match the CMS keyboard, it is the à key you will need to press.

What I have done is create a spreadsheet where I just type all the keys -- first plain and with shift, then withe the right (Alt-Car), then (Ctrl-Car), then (Ctrl-Car-Shift) to make myself a reference.